# How to reload a page with content received by a request made with ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I have an ejs file with a list of items from a database. And I'm trying to develop a search which should update this list, only with the results of the search.

I'm sending a post request to the server, by an ajax function from jQuery.

```
$(".checkbox").on('click', function(){
        let email = $(this).find('input').attr('id')

        $.ajax({
            url: '/dashboard',
            method: 'post',
            data:{email:email},
            success: function(data) {
               alert('success')
            }
        });     
    })
```

The post route performs a full search in the database and return a result. Everything is working as it should but the list in my page remains de same, although I'm sending a different json content by the render function.

```
                $text: {
                    $search: search
                },
            })
            .then(function (results) {
                res.render('dashboard', {
                    name: {},
                    listagemFuncionarios: results,
                    check: {}
                })
            })
            .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is ajax request always get backs the data in the form of json you can not render back a page by requesting through ajax instead you can just get a data back in success in json form and then use it to produce html dynamically through created DOM elements dynamically by Javascript

let suppose you get the data in success function like that

```
[
 {
   name:'xyz',
   email:'mail@xyz.com'
 },
 {
   name:'xyz',
   email:'mail@xyz.com'
 }
]
```

Now you can loop through this data and create html elements let me know if you need more help

Comment: ok, I though in that, but the alert in the success is not working, and I've tried with the complete and is not working either..

Comment: Thats good please mark the answer as solved so it could help others in future